# How to generify a factory method that uses an object cache?

Tags: java, generics, factory

I'm trying to create a static factory method for a set of classes that inherit from a common parent. My idea was to implement something similar to String's intern() method - I want to use the factory method to use a single object whenever equivalent objects are used (instead of having thousands of equivalent objects).

Note that most child classes have no fields, but some of them may have some fields and have different constructor arguments (in which case I override equals and hashCode for the child class), so just using one singleton per class will not work (and I wouldn't want to use singletons anyway).

I have written the code below but for every child class I have to replicate almost identical code in the factory method. I tried writing it using a generic method, but couldn't figure out how.

Is there any way to avoid all this ugly code duplication?

```
public class Parent {
    protected static final Map<Parent, WeakReference<Parent>> pool = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<>());
}

public class Child extends Parent
{
    final int field1;
    final int field2;
    // possibly more fields

    private Child(int field1, int field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public static Child newChildClass(int field1, int field2) {

        Child child = new Child(field1, field2);
        Child obj = (Child)pool.get(child).get();
        if (obj == null)
            pool.put(child, new WeakReference<>(child));
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Child that = (Child) o;
        return field1 == that.field1 && field2 == that.field2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getClass(), field1, field2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note to point out that this cache logic is broken. It assumes hash equality is object equality, which isn't true.  The same cache entry could map to multiple sets of parameters. Not what you want, I think.

Comment: @Gene Can you explain why though?  Calling the factory method with the same parameters will always result in the same object in my program and I'm including the parameters in the calculation of the hash for the map and for any child classes that have fields I override the equals and hashCode methods to reflect the differences in the fields (as mentioned in the comment at the end). What am I missing?

Comment: Hashes can collide. There is no guarantee that `int hash = Objects.hash(ChildClass.class, <parameters>);` will compute a _unique_ number for that class and parameters set. So say Class A with parameters P hashes to the same value as Class B with parameters Q.  You could call the factory for A(P), which would put that in the cache. Then call the factory for B(Q) and get A(P) back.

Comment: @Gene I see your point now, thanks. Should be fixed now.